# How to correctly understand wavelength of EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

When we mention wavelength of EM waves, does the wavelength mean vacuum wavelength?

Is the frequency of every scalar component (x, y and z) $c/λ$, no matter whether it's linearly, elliptically or circularly polarised ?

(Please discuss in SI units)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the given wavelength id the vacuum wavelength  and it applies to all components. Since this is known it is not necessary to allows say 'vacuum wavelength' but you cab think of it this way.

Comment: So can I think in this way: And no matter where the wave is (any medium, maybe vacuum, maybe not) and what polarization state it have (linear, ellipse, or in a mess after scattering or diffraction), wavelength λ (like 800 nm) means the frequency of every scalar component (x, y, z component, real numbers) of E,B,H,D of the wave is c/λ (c is vacuum light speed) (every scalar component of E,B,H,D of the wave has angular frequency 2πc/λ, equivalently)?

Comment: Yes the frequencie is independent of the medium, but the wavelength depends on the medium.